# Discord py - if emoji in new created channel - delete the channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Hey guys!**

I am trying to make a litte ticket-bot for my server -  the problem is that the emoji in the reaction deletes a channel!

So if a member uses the emoji outside the new created channel it will delete the channel :(

**What does my code look like now:**

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = self.client.get_guild(guild_id)
    user_id = payload.user_id
    user = self.client.get_user(payload.user_id)
    message_id = payload.message_id
    emoji = payload.emoji.name

    if message_id == 768765161301213185 and emoji == "":
        member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
        support_role = guild.get_role(760792953718308915)
        category = guild.get_channel(768764177736400906)
        overwrites = {
            guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True),
            support_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
        }

        ticket_nr = random.randint(100,999)
        channel = await category.create_text_channel(f'ticket-{ticket_nr}', overwrites=overwrites)

        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="How can I help you?",
            description="Please wait for a supporter.")
        embed.set_author(name="TiLiKas Ticket Bot")

        for channel_all in guild.text_channels:
            if str(channel_all) == str(channel):
                if user_id != 739740219544305714 and emoji == "":
                    await channel.delete(reason=None)
                else:
                    print("ERROR")
```

**What do I want?**

I want the bot only to responde on the emoji if its used in the new created channel!

Answer (score 0):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=check#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$thumb'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Send me that  reaction, mate')

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send('')
        else:
            await channel.send('')
```

Your `check` method should look something like:

```
def check(reaction, user):
    return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == '' and reaction.message.channel == message.channel
```

This check here, checks:

- the user who is reacting to the message is the same user who started the command.
- the reaction is a thumbs up emoji.
- the reaction is done in the same channel the command was started in.

Comment: That didnt work for me - The reaction from the bot should be ignored - how do I have to change the def command?

Comment: The reaction from the bot is ignored. It is checking "the user who is reacting to the message is the same user who started the command."
You should show your new code.

Comment: The problem is that I call a command and this command sends a message and I just klick on the reaction. I add the reaction in the command - I will show this in my new code too :)

Comment: Should I **edit my first post** or should I use **Answer Your Question**?